# CSS: How to remove a tint with a transition from a background image on hover?

Tags: html, css, animation, css-transitions

I have the following HTML and CSS samples where I have an image tinted with the color red. When I hover over it, the tint is removed - this is achieved by just inserting the image again without the tint.

The problem is that it is very instantaneous - has no transition. I attempted to insert a transition but it doesn't seem to be working.

```css
div {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,
      rgba(250, 0, 0, 0.5),
      rgba(250, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/cat.png");
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-size: 300px;
  transition: all 2s ease-out;
}

div:hover {
  background-image: url("https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/cat.png");
  transition: all 2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
    
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are trying to animate `background-image` which can't be done,

why dont you use `after` pseudo element instead

```css
div {
  background-image: url("https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/cat.png");
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-size: 300px;
  position: relative;
}


div:after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: red;
opacity: 0.5;
transition: .5s;
}

div:hover:after {
opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
    
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Some CSS properties are [animatable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties), and some are NOT. Unfortunately, you cannot apply `transition` to `background-image`, but you still have options:

You might use `box-shadow` to achieve the desired effect:

```css
div {
  background: url("https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/cat.png") 50% / 300px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 150px #f008;
  transition: 1s ease-out;
}

div:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 150px #0000;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Or use `background-blend-mode` if [you're open to](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-backgroundblendmode):

```css
div {
  background:#f008 url("https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/cat.png") 50% / 300px;
  background-blend-mode: overlay;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  transition: 1s ease-out;
}

div:hover {
  background-color:#0000;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Another option is using `border`:

```css
div {
  background:url("https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/cat.png") 50% / 300px;
  border:solid 150px #f008;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  transition: 1s ease-out;
}

div:hover {
  border-color:#0000;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Or you might use absolutely positioned (pseudo-)element, as other answers suggested.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      .elem1 {
        background-image: linear-gradient(
            to bottom,
            rgba(250, 0, 0, 0.5),
            rgba(250, 0, 0, 0.5)
          ),
          url("https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/cat.png");
        height: 300px;
        width: 300px;
        background-size: 300px;
        transition: all 2s;
        position: relative;
      }

      .elem2 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-image: url("https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/cat.png");
        opacity: 0;
        background-size: cover;
      }

      .elem2:hover {
        transition: all 2s;
        opacity: 1;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="elem1">
      <div class="elem2"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```